# QuotaExceededError in my AMP page only in safari browser

Tags: safari, amp-html

I got **QuotaExceededError** in my AMP page only in **safari** browser.
In some Safari browser page is working perfectly, but in some safari browser, I got this error.
Even I am Checking this in normal browser page(Not in Incognito mode).
Please give me a solution if you have any idea regarding this.
[image]

Comment: please let me know the version of browser